# Request New System Time on Runtime when Timezone Changes

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, windows-services

I have a windows service that monitors System Events when the local system timezone has changed, which then executes an event querying for the new TimeZone and new System Time. I followed `[Microsoft documentation][1]` but i cannot get the new System Time using `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()` after the Timezone Changes. How can I solve this issue?

[Debugging TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpzLU.png)

I also found that the TimeZone.CurrentTimezone does not update the Standard Timezone but only the DaylightName after the TimeZone changed on the system.
[Logs when TimeZone Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKUeH.png)

Ideally i'd like to not only get the new System Time but TimeZone Standard Name as well. But with the New System Time and Daylight Name i can implement the rest of my application.

See my code below:

```
 //when service starts
    public void Start()
    {

        //timer stops
        _timer.Start();

        //Event when services Starts
        ServiceStarted();

        //Getting access to the System Events, and monitoring for time Zone changes.
        SystemEvents.TimeChanged += SystemEvents_TimeChanged;


    }

    //System Time event when Time Changes
    private void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        TimeZoneInfo.Local.ToString();
        TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToString();

                    string[] lines = new string[]
        {
            $"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} The Local System Time has changed",
            $"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} Previous Time zone {TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName.ToString()}",
            $"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} New Time Zone {TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.DaylightName.ToString()} and the time is {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}"


        };

        //create log file and add the event message
        File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Temp\Heartbeat_Log.txt", lines);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net caches the system local time zone for performance reasons, so if you're specifically watching for changes, you'll need to clear the cache.

In your event handler, call:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.clearcacheddata

Also, the `TimeZone` class is deprecated.  Use only `TimeZoneInfo`.

Comment: Thanks, i notice that TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData(); also clears the cached DateTime class.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about that.  There's nothing "cached" in `DateTime`.  It's just a struct that has a field with a value.